# get consecutive rows mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm creating a Rock Papper Scisors game, the problem that i'm facing is that i need to set a winner based on a Best Of 3, 5 or 7, and to do so i need to calculate the number of consecutive querys my bet table is simple:

BO3

```
ID|GAME_ID|WINNER
1 |145    |15
2 |145    |14
3 |145    |15
4 |145    |15
```

15 needs to win , how can i calculate it in mysql?

ex:

```
GAME_ID|WINNER|CONSECUTIVES
    145|15    |2
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to need variables for this:

```
select gameid, winner, max(rn)
from (select s.*,
             (@rn := if(@gw = concat_ws(':', gameid, winner), @rn + 1,
                        if(@gw := concat_ws(':', gameid, winner), 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from scores s cross join
           (select @gw := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by s.id
     ) s
group by gameid, winner;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d97ce/3) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: you are not considering that if the previous result be differentit will not count , ex, winneris: 15,15,14 is 1 for 14

Comment: @talles_jp . . . I fixed that.  Handling multiple variables is a bit of a pain with variables, so the variable keys are concatenated together.

Comment: @GordonLinoff almost complete sir , it just has a problem , if i put it to list the winner it  will display inverted values, in you'r case 12 istead of 14 , but it is almost complete =D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select y.winner, 
  case when y2.cnt <= 3 then 'Best of 3' 
       when y2.cnt <= 5 then 'Best of 5' 
       when y2.cnt <= 7 then 'Best of 7' 
   end, count(*)
from yourtable y join (
  select count(*) cnt, gameid
  from yourtable
  group by gameid) y2 on y.gameid = y2.gameid
group by y.gameid, y.winner, y2.cnt
having count(*) = 2 and y2.cnt <= 3 or 
 count(*) = 3 and y2.cnt <= 5 or 
 count(*) = 4 and y2.cnt <= 7
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3af42/6)

Comment: didnt worled i  need something that outputs like this:

game|winner|consecutives
145   |15        | 2

Comment: @talles_jp -- what are `consecutives`?  I was guessing at your output before you updated your question...